# ui-router annotating resolve with parameters for minifying?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, minify

ui-router breaks when minifying if the code isn't annotated properly. I have done this and most of my routes work, but this in particular does not:

```
var authRedirect = function(s) {
    return ['$state', '$q', 'AuthService', function($state, $q, AuthService) {
        var d = $q.defer();
        var is_auth = AuthService.checkAuth();
        if(!is_auth) {
            d.reject();
            $state.go(s);
        } else 
           d.resolve();
        return d.promise;
    }];
}

// ...

.state('secret', {
    url: '/secret',
    controller: 'TestCtrl',
    templatesUrl: '/test.html',
    resolve: { authRedirect: authRedirect('other') }
})
.state('other', { .... } )
```

I'm passing in another state into my `resolve` function, which should redirect to that state if some condition isn't met. I use this resolve function in several other routes, so it's a handy way of keeping the ui-router code clean.

While the non-minified version is working fine, the minified version of this doesn't work (it does nothing). But it seems like I've annotated it properly since no errors were thrown. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try by updating the code like this

```
.state('secret', {
    url: '/secret',
    controller: 'TestCtrl',
    templatesUrl: '/test.html',
    resolve: { authRedirect: function() { return authRedirect('other')} }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update the code with

```
.state('secret', {
    url: '/secret',
    controller: 'TestCtrl',
    templatesUrl: '/test.html',
    resolve: { authRedirect: ['authRedirect', function(authRedirect){ return authRedirect('other')}] }
})
```

Comment: Huh, this makes the entire route break, instead of just the redirect portion.

Comment: @rublex - I am pretty sure this should work. Can you please share me the updated code?

Comment: I think you are right with putting my global func in its own Service. I will try that. But other than polluting the global namespace, is there a particularly sinister reason why authRedirect as a global function is bad?

Comment: @Rublex - I have the same reason as the one you interpreted. Angular lays a protocol, and we should go by that. That is what I believe.